# setting @ApiQuery optional and just 1 parameter to select Nestjs

Tags: nestjs

I'm doing mi Swagger and in one endPoint y COULD receive a boolean parameter, if i dont get the parameter its fine.
When i receive the parameter and its true it will do a special filter. The question is, can i tell to Swagger the option its optional and if the client choose to select a option it will be only true?
[image]

As you can see the "OnlyActive" is optional, thats good, now i need that the posibles option only be
"--"
"true"

and nothing more

This is the fragment of code
[image]
Lane 20

thank u a lot